# How To Save Multiple ListBox Value in a single row and in a single column

Tags: c#, sql, linq, listbox

I want to save multiple list box value into a single field of a table using linq to entity. this is my code. any suggestion?

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < lb2.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var e1 = new employee() { emp_skill = lb2.Items[i].Text };
        je.employee.AddObject(e1);
    }
    je.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your data is collection of string and you want to save it as single string. The following code make those collection of string become single string separated by semicolon, then you can save it as single row single column data:

```
   protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var semicolonSeparatedString = "";
        var e1 = (from emp in je.employee where emp.emp_email == txtmail.Text select emp).FirstOrDefault();
        for (int index = 0; index < lb2.Items.Count; index++)
        {
            //no need to add separator for the first item
            if (index == 0) semicolonSeparatedString += lb2.Items[index];
            else semicolonSeparatedString += ";" + lb2.Items[index];
        }
        //data formatted as single string and ready to be saved
        e1.emp_skill = semicolonSeparatedString;
        je.SaveChanges();
```

And when you want to get it back as collection of string simply use Split() extension method :

```
//load data from datasource (database or file)
var semicolonSeparatedString = je.employee.FirstOrDefault(o => o.name == "employeeName").Select(o => o.emp_skill);
//split to get the single string data back to array of string
var items = semicolonSeparatedString.Split(';');
foreach(var item in items)
{
    lb2.Items.Add(item);
}
```

I tested the code with ListBox in windows form.

**UPDATE :**
I update the code to include saving and loading data from database, those parts are untested. My code based on yours in question and several assumptions.

Comment: The name 'SaveMyData' does not exist in the current context

Comment: yes, SaveMyData() and LoadMyData() function is not exist currently. You supposed to make those two function, and do saving and loading data operation there. I assumed you already know how to save and query your database from c# code.

Comment: No. I am new in .Net. Can you please help me with the exact code.?

Comment: Yes. I have two tables in the database. One is Employee, another one is Education. EMployee Table has name, email(p_key) and skill.. and education table has a foreign key with the employee table.. in the aspx page i first enter the name and email, then fill up the education details, then i want to save the skills from list box.. I am using Linq to Entities

Comment: check my update, hope that works despite there are lot of assumption i made.

Comment: where to write the second code.? I wrote the first part under the buttonclick event

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43203/discussion-between-har07-and-sayantan-das)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to serialize the values to a single byte stream, then save that data into the database. There are many ways to serialize values, for example binary serialization or XML serialization or any custom serialization mechanism. You are supposed to change the type of the column accordingly (for example, for binary serialization the BLOB-type of your database would be best-suited).

Comment: How to implement this.? can you suggest some link.?

Comment: Just google for it, there are tons of examples. Here is one for binary serialization: [link](http://tech.pro/tutorial/618/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file)